# Actions on Google; Transaction API

Tags: actions-on-google

I have been thinking about monetization on `Actions on Google`. Document says that there are three types of monetization, but I am not sure which is an appropriate one for a project. I would like to let a user to unlock more digital recourse inside my app. For example, if it is a vocabulary app, then a user pays money to get thirty words to learn.

Which one is most suitable and why?

- **Physical transactions with Google Pay**
- **Physical transactions with merchant-managed payments**
- **Digital transactions**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These would be [Digital Goods](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/digital/dev-guide-digital). There is no physical product involved - you will not need the user's address to send them something. You are just giving them more access in your Action.

Comment: The thing is does it support digital purchase only in an Assistant app? Seems like you can buy stuff that is available in Android app which is in Google Play Store, if my understanding is not wrong